# Core Data countForFetchRequest for Distinct Entity Instances

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I seem to be unable to get the countForFetchRequest method of NSManagedObjectContext to correctly count distinct instances. Some questions about counting distinct instances have been asked around here already, but they don't seem to address this exact problem, so please bear with me.

As an example, I define an entity 'MyEntity' with a single attribute 'data' and then create a few instances programmatically.

```
var error: NSError?

for i in 1 ... 10
{
    for j in 1 ... 3
    {
        var entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyEntity",
                    inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as MyEntity
        entity.data = i
    }
}

managedObjectContext!.save(&error)
```

This creates 30 instances with 10 different values for the attribute. I expect a distinct count to return 10, like it does when querying the sqlite database.

```
sqlite> select count(*) from zmyentity;
30
sqlite> select count(distinct(zdata)) from zmyentity;
10
```

In fact, when executing the corresponding fetch operation, I get 10 results.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest()
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
request.entity = entityDescription

let property = entityDescription!.propertiesByName["data"] as NSPropertyDescription
request.propertiesToFetch = [property]
request.returnsDistinctResults = true
request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

let result = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

println("Count \(result!.count)")
```

If, however, instead of actually retrieving and then counting these results I just want to count them using countForFetchRequest, the count comes out as 30.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest()
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
request.entity = entityDescription

let property = entityDescription!.propertiesByName["data"] as NSPropertyDescription
request.propertiesToFetch = [property]
request.returnsDistinctResults = true
request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

let count = managedObjectContext!.countForFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

println("Count \(count)")
```

The method is documented as follows:

> Returns the number of objects a given fetch request would have
>   returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:.

so I wouldn't really expect the results to be different. As an aside, neither of the two ways of counting above is working at all when the underlying data store is XML instead of sqlite, while in principle, and according to documentation, the data store type should be transparent.

Now here's my question: Is this behaviour expected? Is it documented somewhere? Am I overlooking something, is there anything I can configure to make countForFetchRequest work? This example has only 30 instances, but in my real code it's more like a few hundred thousand, so the idea of loading them all into a big dictionary in memory just to count them doesn't appeal to me. If something like an SQL SELECT DISTINCT could be done using the Core Data API, that would be preferable.

Comment: Looking at the underlying SQL, CoreData includes the DISTINCT keyword when you execute the fetch request, but doesn't include it in the `countForFetchRequest`.  Seems like a bug to my mind, but Apple may have their reasons.  But I have just noticed (debugging a completely different problem) that `NSFetchResultsController` does generate the right kind of query (i.e. "COUNT(DISTINCT ...)") in certain circumstances - it may be that you could get what you need by fine tuning an FRC.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks a lot for debugging this. For my purposes fiddling with the NSFetchResultsController is a bit of an overkill to count instances and I can work around it. But it's good to know that it wasn't just user error; I was starting to feel a bit stupid.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue where executeFetchRequest returns correct results but countForFetchRequest returns total number instead of distinct count.